# Extending jquery ui widget - how to access parent event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a jQuery widget which extends from [ui.slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/). I'd like to have a custom method which executes on the 'slide' event. I tried overriding the parent's option just like when using the slider widget normally, but I ran into this problem with variable scopes:

```
$.widget( "ui.myslider", $.ui.slider, {
    _create: function() {
        this.foo = "bar";

        // Outputs "bar"
        this._mySlide();

        // Outputs "undefined" when triggered
        this.options.slide = this._mySlide;

        $.ui.slider.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    _mySlide: function() {
        alert(this.foo);
    }
}
```

How can I trigger my function on the slide event AND have access to my variable?

**Edit:**
Link to ui.slider source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js

**Edit:** Solution

```
$.widget( "ui.myslider", $.ui.slider, {
    _create: function() {
        $.ui.slider.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);
        this.foo = "bar";
    },
    _slide: function() {
        $.ui.slider.prototype._slide.apply(this, arguments);
        alert(this.foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In jQuery UI >= 1.9, you can use the `_super` method instead:

```
_slide: function() {
  this._super();
  // equivalent to $.Widget.prototype._slide.call( this );
}
```

or `superApply`:

```
_slide: function() {
  this._superApply(arguments);
  // equivalent to $.Widget.prototype._slide.apply( this, arguments );
}
```