# Extending jQuery UI widgets - override parent events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to extend the [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) widget.  In my custom widget, I need to be able to override the [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event, while ideally also allowing the user of the widget to attach their own handler to that event as well.

Here's a jsfiddle of one of my attempts: http://jsfiddle.net/nN46R/

My first attempt (which is in the jsfiddle) was to bind to the event in `_create`:

```
$.widget("custom.myautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super("_create");

        // Doesn't work
        this.element.bind('autocompleteselect', function() {
            alert('Handling autocompleteselect!');
        });
    }
});
```

This didn't work. It *will* trigger if you change `autocompleteselect` to `select`, but only if you highlight any text within the textbox - but that's just jQuery's [select](https://api.jquery.com/select/) handler firing, not jQuery UI's [autocompleteselect](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select). Not what I want.

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992296/extending-jquery-ui-widget-how-to-access-parent-event), I tried defining a `_select` method within the widget:

```
$.widget("custom.myautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super("_create");
    },
    _select: function (event, ui) {
        alert('Handling select!');
    }
});
```

That also didn't work. I tried the same with just `select` (no underscore), but no luck.

The only thing that worked was to pass in a default handler using the `options` array, like so ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kB8L9/1/)):

```
$.widget("custom.myautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    options: {
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Handling select!');
        }
    }
});
```

But this has a couple problems. First, it doesn't look like it's possible to call any other methods in the custom widget from within the handler:

```
$.widget("custom.myautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    options: {
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Handling select!');

            // Doesn't work:
            // Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method '_myCustomSelectHandler'
            this._myCustomSelectHandler();
        }
    },
    _myCustomSelectHandler: function (event, ui) {
        alert('In _myCustomSelectHandler!');
    }
});
```

Second, if the user defines their own `select` handler, then mine won't fire anymore:

```
$("#tags").myautocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (e, ui) {
        alert("Muahaha! Me (the user) just overrode the select handler, and now yours won't get called!");
    }
});
```

So that doesn't really look like a solution.

So, is there any way I could extend the autocomplete widget and override the `select` handler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out! In the first code sample, all I had to do is bind to the `myautocompleteselect` event instead of `autocompleteselect`:

http://jsfiddle.net/nN46R/1/

```
$.widget("custom.myautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super("_create");

        // Works! Bind to the "myautocompleteselect" event, not
        // "autocompleteselect".
        this.element.bind('myautocompleteselect', function() {
            alert('Something selected!');
        });
    }
});
```

Apparently, the full name of the event that gets raised is the name of the widget concatenated with the name of the event (`select`). This is a custom widget, so you're supposed to use the custom widget's name, which in my example is `myautocomplete`.

As a side note, this is also relevant for the widget user if they want to bind to any events in their code, such as the autocomplete menu opening or closing. If this was the base autocomplete widget, they would bind to the menu opening event using:

```
$('#tags').bind('autocompleteopen', function(event, ui) {
    console.log('autocomplete menu opening');
});
```

However, if they're using the custom widget `myautocomplete` (which extends `autocomplete`), they would need to bind to the `myautocompleteopen` event instead:

```
$('#tags').bind('myautocompleteopen', function(event, ui) {
    console.log('custom autocomplete menu opening');
});
```

The event names of jQuery UI widget events are namespaced - important to keep in mind!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. I couldn't have identified the reason without your answer.